# Duplicate folders in contacts Outlook 2010 merge them

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have 4 different folders for Outlook contacts, three personal folders and one suggested contact folder. How do I merge these into one because I have to search all three in order to find one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just drag and drop emails between each user. You can also select multiple emails and drag in bulk.

However, you can search all mail items in Outlook 2010 and "All Outlook Items" which will do all your accounts.

[image]